# How to add a reset button to every HTML input field in Firefox?

Tags: firefox-extensions

Is there an extension that could modify the DOM of pages so that for every input field, there would be an extra button that resets the content of the field ? I'm often in a situation where I have copied some text, and I have to paste in an input field that is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Clear Fields](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/clear-fields/)  is what you want.

Toolbar buttons that clear:

> - Address Field
> - Search Field
> - Search Field of the Official Google Toolbar
> - Search Field of Web Search Pro
> - Find Field (currently broken in ffx 4)
> - **All Text Fields, Password Fields and Checkboxes in the viewed page!**
> - Bookmark and History Panel Search Fields
> - Search Field of the Official Yahoo Toolbar
> - *NEW* in-field clear buttons for Address, Search and Find fields

[image: Clear Fields]

Comment: I'm looking for something more intrusive.  Fields should have their own clear button.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't have access to the solution you're searching for (different computer, etc.), if you double click the field it should select the hole input and then you can paste on top of it. If that doesn't work (several words on the field) then you can press CTRL+A and then paste (CTRL+V) on top of it. Hope that helps.

Comment: One of the reasons I don't want to interact with the content of the text field, is because I'm using middle mouse button paste (a.k.a X-Window cut buffer IIRC) on Linux, and this would replace the selection. I'm also looking for a 'lazy' solution that doesn't require the keyboard.